# jquery, .data() hover one div and change the content and image div on two other div's

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#MenuBar1 li").mouseover(function() {
        $("#back").attr("src", $(this).data("img"));
        $('.description').text($(this).data('description'));
    }).mouseout(function() { 
        $("#back").attr("src", $("#back").data("original"));
    });
});
```

​HTML code:

```
<div>
    <div style="width: 377px; position:relative; left: 395px;">
        <ul id="MenuBar1" class="MenuBarHorizontal">
            <div style="height:20px;">
                <li id="button1" data-img="http://http://demo/images/anne.jpg" width="357" height="241" border="0">
                    <a href="#">Anywhere</a>
                </li>
            </div>
            <div style="height:20px;">
                <li id="button2" data-img="http://demo/images/Banner.jpg">
                    <a href="#">ware</a>
                </li>
            </div>
            <div style="height:20px;">
                <li id="button3" data-img="http://demo/images/Banner.jpg">
                    <a href="#">Demand</a>
                </li>
            </div>
            <div style="height:20px;">
                <li id="button4" data-img="http:http://demo/images/Bans.jpg">
                    <a href="#">CM</a>
                </li>
            </div>
            <div style="height:20px;">
                <li id="button5" data-img="http://demo/images/eat.jpg">
                    <a href="#">Key</a>
                </li>
            </div>
            </a></li></div>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 357px; position: relative; top: -380px;" id="content"> 
        <img id="back"src="http://demo/images/Banner.jpg"data-original="http://demo/images/Banner.jpg" alt="e.s.t" /> 
    </div>
<div>
    <p>put text content here for each hover</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You'll need to explain your problem/question more than just dropping in a chunk of code.

Comment: Can you explain your problem more clearly.. Also a bit of HTML along with the code should make a lot more sense..

Comment: I copt and paste but kept saying spacing issue, my first time here. I nned it to look like http://www.local10.com/ top news but using jquery. I have 12 links and i need when hover a

Comment: You seem to have some malformed HTML there. You should also edit your question to provide additional information and context. (Use the "edit" link below the tags.)

Comment: <ul id="MenuBar1" class="MenuBarHorizontal">
        <div style="height:20px;">
          <li id="button1" data-img="http://demo/images/salesforce_Banner.jpg" width="357" height="241" border="0"><a href="#">Salesforce CRM CTI -  Oracle Contact Center Anywhere</a></li>
        </div></ul></div>

Comment: I have 12 links on the right side of my page and when hover over a link it needs to show a div for the image and a div for the text, when taken off over it returns back to the original text and image which is the first link.

Comment: @dyscool, use jsFiddle.net to give a sample of your code.

Comment: lol, jsFiddle got me this far, got the div with the image going now i just need to know how and what to ust for the div with the text content. I research .text, .bind, etc..

Comment: code does not after uploading to web. in jsFiddles it works but by it exactly the same or modified to fit my needs, it remains static –

Comment: sorry again but this code is not working for the text div. Jquery: }).mouseout(function() { $("#back").attr("src", $("#back").data("original"));$('.description').text($('.description').data('chan‌​ge')); }); HTML: <div id="change" class="description" style="background-color: #CCC; width: 338px; position: relative; top: -359px; left: 5px; padding: 15px 10px 15px; color: #414141; font: arial, Trebuchet MS; height: 266px;"> change text for each link with each picture then set back to default </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like malformed HTML in the image tag

```
<img id="back"src="http://demo/images/Banner.jpg"data-original="http://demo/images/Banner.jpg" alt="e.s.t" />
```

Missing space between between id , data attributes...

```
 <img id="back" src="http://demo/images/Banner.jpg" data-original="http://demo/images/Banner.jpg" alt="e.s.t" />
```

**EDIT**

[Check FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/rapat/6/)

I have added the description class to the div.

Also added the data-description attribute to the li tags..

Check the example above..

**UPDATED**

```
   $(document).ready(function() {

        var defaultText  = '';
        $("#MenuBar1 li").mouseover(function() {
            $("#back").attr("src", $(this).data("img"));
            defaultText = $(".description").text();
            $(".description").text($(this).data("description"));
        }).mouseout(function() {
            $("#back").attr("src", $("#back").data("original"));
            $(".description").text(defaultText);
    });​
```

You are trying to access the defaultText variable which has scope only in the first function.  Try declaring it outside of the  mouseover event .. You just now encountered a scoping bug :D ;

Comment: Thank you, i check, it was the way i copied it on this site and not the code itself.

Comment: from what I read, I guess I am trying to figure out how to combine .text and .data to make this site work. there are many ways from what i see.

Comment: Extra </a></li></div>  just before the end of </ul> tag

Comment: I copied that code from an example, trying to figure how to input the div with the text. the image seem to be working on fiddle

Comment: You need to have <div class="description"></div> in your code .. Also need to add data-description attribute to your li's

Comment: Like this: <div style="height:20px;" class="description"><li id="button1" data-img="http://http://demo/images/anne.jpg" width="357" height="241" border="0" data-description:"text";><a href="#">Anywhere</a><div>Place Content Here</div>

Comment: Also need to include data-description attribute to each to each li tag.. As you are trying to access the data("description")  of the li..

Comment: So the Jqeury code is correct and I just need to fix my html?

Comment: Yes please.. jQuery code seems to be fine but attributes in HTML are missing.. Fix that and it should be fine

Comment: code does not after uploading to web. in jsFiddles it works but by it exactly the same or modified to fit my needs, it remains static

Comment: <script type="text/jscript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#MenuBar1 li").mouseover(function() {
        $("#back").attr("src", $(this).data("img"));
        $('.description').text($(this).data('description'));
    }).mouseout(function() { 
        $("#back").attr("src", $("#back").data("original"));
      $('.description').text($('.description').data('description'));
    });
});

Comment: What are you trying to do here..    $('.description').text($('.description').data('description')); .. In the last line of mouseout

Comment: one moment for the rest, it's not going thru

Comment: return back to first, but even without it, still no results

Comment: <div style="width: 357px; position: relative; top: -380px;" id="content"> 
        <img id="back"src="http://demo/images/Banner.jpg"data-original="http://demo/images/Banner.jpg" alt="e.s.t" /> 
    </div>
<div><div class="description" style="background-color: #CCC; width: 357px; position: relative; top: -260px; left: 5px; padding: 3px 10px;" >
      <p>Testing jquery</p>
</div>
    <p>put text content here for each hover</p>
</div>

Comment: Looks like a problem here.. Malformed HTML  data-original="http://demo/…; alt="  .. Data original was not closed properly

Comment: I am new to jquery, learning as i go, is there a syntax missing?

Comment: Use this and try .. <img id="back"src="demo/images/Banner.jpg" data-original="http://demo/…;" alt="e.s.t" />

Comment: Did you incclude your js file for this page. I do not see it anywhere

Comment: yes, it's there top area line 83-91 on the view source. took out $('.description').text($('.description').data('description'));

Comment: You have not included jQuery Library in the first place.. Place this before your javascript <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: When you check the console section after hitting F12 in your browser, you see $ is not defined.. This means jQuery is not referenced

Comment: Also in line 83 <script type="text/jscript">    should be <script type="text/javascript">

Comment: omg, you are the best in what you do, thank you so so very much. you are awesome, I am truly greatful

Comment: one more thing and i feel like I am done. do i use the same code to return the text back to it's original state before rolling over like the images?

Comment: glad I could be of help :)... yup try that.. Set it back to the original in the mouseout event

Comment: sorry again but this code is not working for the text div. Jquery: }).mouseout(function() { 
        $("#back").attr("src", $("#back").data("original"));$('.description').text($('.description').data('change'));
    }); HTML:  <div id="change" class="description" style="background-color: #CCC; width: 338px; position: relative; top: -359px; left: 5px; padding: 15px 10px 15px; color: #414141; font: arial, Trebuchet MS; height: 266px;"> change text for each link with each picture then set back to default </div>

Comment: revised, still no change. <script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function() { $("#MenuBar1 li").mouseover(function() { $("#back").attr("src", $(this).data("img")); var defaultText= $(".description").text(); $(".description").text($(this).data("description")); }).mouseout(function() { $("#back").attr("src", $("#back").data("original")); $(".description").text(defaultText); }); }); </script>

Comment: <div class="description" style="background-color: #CCC; width: 338px; position: relative; top: -359px; left: 5px; padding: 5px 10px 15px; color: #414141; font: arial, Trebuchet MS; height: 256px;" id="Text" >

Comment: so i added var defaultText= $(".description").text(); to my mouseover and tested it, still no result.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for 2 li's .. So that this can be tested

Comment: May be it's how i called it out on my div tag because i test it on fiddle, no response. $(document).ready(function() {

        var defaultText  = '.description';
        $("#MenuBar1 li").mouseover(function() {
            $("#back").attr("src", $(this).data("img"));
            defaultText = $(".description").text();
            $(".description").text($(this).data("description"));
        }).mouseout(function() {
            $("#back").attr("src", $("#back").data("original"));
            $(".description").text(defaultText);
    });       <div class="description" id="defaultText" ></div

Comment: Why don't you try .html() instead of .text() for $('.description')

Comment: still no luck not even on fiddle, now the image part is not working as well.                                                      $(document).ready(function() {    var defaultText  = '.description';
        $("#MenuBar1 li").mouseover(function() {
            $("#back").attr("src", $(this).data("img"));
            defaultText = $(".description").html();
            $(".description").html($(this).data("description"));
        }).mouseout(function() {
            $("#back").attr("src", $("#back").data("original"));
            $(".description").html(defaultText);
    });​

Comment: I called it out like so <div class="description" id="Text" >

Comment: Can you update the older fiddle with the description text so that I can have a look at it

Comment: Also try this  ..  var defaultText = $(".description").html();
$("#MenuBar1 li").mouseover(function() {
    $("#back").attr("src", $(this).data("img"));
    $(".description").html($(this).data("description"));
}).mouseout(function() {
    $("#back").attr("src", $("#back").data("original"));
    $(".description").html(defaultText);
});​

Comment: You were missing the Closing tag DOM Ready.. Try this  http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/xDaL8/1/

Comment: lol, it's always the simple things that gets over looked, thank you, your the only helpful person around here. I'm grateful because you don't have to do this.

Comment: That's fine .. Not a problem at all.. :D .. So are all your problems fixed ??